# Regarding groupTextTpl

Tags: extjs

How do I get the total number of items in a group?

For example, `values.rs.length` is not giving me the total number of items in a group instead it gives the number of items displayed in that group.  I want to display somthing like this:

`Customer: Initial Asser Billing Unit (10 Items of 20)`

... where 20 is the total number of items in that group.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you'd want to query the underlying GroupingStore for that, not the template used to render the view.  You should be able to query the store by whatever field is being grouped on to get the count of records that match.